# Importing IronPython dlls in Unity

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, dll

This error keeps on showing up in unity whenever I import the dll files in the plugin folder, what does this mean and how can I fix it?

> Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException:
>   The classes in the module cannot be loaded. at (wrapper
>   managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (bool)

Comment: What happens if you switch Unity from .Net 3.5 to 4.6?

Comment: Isn't that going to affect the script, and many changes in the game?

Comment: No. It will simply use .NET 4.6. I do believe that IronPython is complied with higher version of .NET you are currently using.  I may be wrong but it's worth giving it a try

Comment: Am using .NET 2.0, but I can't find .NET 4.6 to switch it, Am using Unity 5.3.4, How is this going to work?

Comment: I haven't used IronPython but noticed they do mention providing different assembly versions for embedding.  Try using the DLLs found in platforms\net35 (within your IronPython directory)

Comment: which dll you are using?

Comment: These: 
**IronPython.dll
IronPython.Modules.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.dll
Microsoft.Dynamic.dll**